# laravel8- php artisan serve command error

Tags: laravel-artisan, laravel-8

I am opening laravel9 project file. artisan file is here. when i write `php artisan serve`  command is giving follow error

PHP Warning: require(/home/saide/Desktop/saide_backoffice_web_app/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/saide/Desktop/saide_backoffice_web_app/artisan on line 18 PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/saide/Desktop/saide_backoffice_web_app/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/saide/Desktop/saide_backoffice_web_app/artisan on line 18

How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

What was before you try to run this command?

Have you try `composer install` before `php artisan serve`

It Will be good to get more information.

Comment: composer uploaded. But somposer install is giving follow error.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Comment: then you get the solution - you need to solve those errors 
autoload.php generates by the composer
which errors it shows?

Comment: I solved problem with this command: 
" composer update --ignore-platform-reqs "

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

try `composer install` or `composer update` before `php artisan serve`